# email validation for combination of chars, numbers and only one @ symbol and not more than two . (Dots)

Tags: c#

can anyone help me with the following:

I need email validation regex epression for combination of chars, numbers and only one @ symbol and not more than two . (Dots).

Comment: Have you tried googling for regexes? There are loads that people have done and posted online.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](http://www.regexr.com/). Its a good start for learning regular expressions.
Something like **[\w-.]+@([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4}** should do the trick